# does nhibernate.burrow work with mvc.net and dot net 4.0 framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-burrow

I am thinking of using nHibernate.Burrow in my mvc.net application.  However there are several troubling things that I have read and I am hoping to get them sorted out before I embark on the project:

Are there any issues with running .Burrow with mvc.net?

Are there issues with running .Burrow with the 4.0 framework?

How tightly coupled is .Burrow with the nHibernate?  I have read several things indicating that I have to use the same version of nHibernate as was used to create the .Burrow binaries.

Any other thoughts that people have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use Burrow with appropriate NHibernate version. If you want to use it with another one you can try to put [assemblyRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(VS.71).aspx) in web.config file.

And I wouldn't try to use Burrow with MVC. Yes, it has Session magement and some other usefull featrures, but they are tied to ASP.NET Web Forms.

As a base framework for mvc applications I would suggest [Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/). It has all required binaries and all versions are latest.

Comment: Probably false =) ASP.NET MVC is just a part of the ASP.NET. Isn't it obvious that Sly meant ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: I was talking about web forms. Paco just always minuses my answers, don't know why :)